# Using Expansions in the Eventbrite API

Tags: eventbrite

Can someone tell me why the following does not work..??

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/45XXXXX62/?expand=attendees/?token=KXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I get the following error, and only get the error when I use expansions -

{
    "status_code": 401, 
    "error_description": "An OAuth token is required for all requests", 
    "error": "NO_AUTH"
}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are putting the URL in the wrong manner.

You should put call API

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/45XXXXX62/?expand=attendees&token=KXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

If you are not able to get it write then check your token.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the Order owner and using your Personal OAuth Token? If not, you'll receive a 401 as only someone with those permissions can access that endpoint.

Comment: Please phrase answers as answers.  if you phrase them as questions people will flag them as low-quality posts.  It appears you have a possible explanation for the OP's problem.  So write it properly as a positive answer.